# Микросервисная, монолитная и SOA архитектуры

Tags: архитектура

Возник такой вопрос при изучении различных архитектур разработки на просторах интернета.
Вопрос глупый, но хотела бы разобраться.
Монолит, микросервисы и SOA это все архитектурные подходы или виды архитектуры?
Очень много информации в интернете и везде называют по разному.

Comment: Давайте начнём от точки, где вы приведете определения того, что для вас есть вид архитектуры, а что есть подход. Лучше со ссылкой на надёжный источник. Так как нет 100% единства даже тут.

Comment: В реальном мире IT нет той строгости терминологии, как в традиционных учебниках. С этим придется смириться. Все понимается в зависимости от контекста.